# Why does pyfftw output zero?

Tags: python, pyfftw

This must be a stupid question but I could not figure what is wrong by myself. I wanted to test pyfftw so I ran the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw

a = np.random.randn(2,64,64)
b = np.zeros(2,64,33)*np.complex(0.)

pyfftw.FFTW(a,b,axes = (-2,-1), direction = 'FFTW_FORWARD')
```

I expect that the array `b` to be changed to the Fourier modes of array `a`. But it turns out that `b` is still all zeros. So what is wrong here? Can anyone give a hint? Thank you very much.

Here is the follow up. Thanks AKX and Hamaza for pointing out that I should run the execute() method to get the FFT done. But Now there is another issue. I tried calling pyfftw in a self-defined function. The output shows that the input array is changed to all zeros.

```
def f2fh(f):
    ftmp = np.copy(f)
    nz,nx,ny = f.shape
    nky = ny
    nkx = (nx/2)+1
    fh = np.zeros((nz,nky,nkx))*np.complex(0.)
    print 'ksksks',ftmp.shape,fh.shape,ftmp
    pyfftw.FFTW(ftmp, fh, axes = (-2,-1), direction = 'FFTW_FORWARD').execute()
    print 'a',ftmp
    return fh
```

The output is
[image]

Can anyone give a hint what is wrong this time? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem? I also encountered the same bug(?) even if I did the "execute" run.

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling `execute()`. Via [the docs](https://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#pyfftw.FFTW):

> The actual FFT or iFFT is performed by calling the [`execute()`](https://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#pyfftw.FFTW.execute) method.

> `execute()`:
> Execute the planned operation, taking the correct kind of FFT of the input array (i.e. FFTW.input_array), and putting the result in the output array (i.e. FFTW.output_array).

You might also want to use the "easier" interfaces described [over here](https://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/sphinx/tutorial.html#quick-and-easy-the-pyfftw-interfaces-module):

> `b = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fft(a)`

Comment: You should have asked the followup question as a separate question, but the documentation says: "input_array and output_array should be numpy arrays. The contents of these arrays will be destroyed by the planning process during initialisation." If you need the original content, pass a copy to FFTW.

Comment: You can also call the [FFTW object itself](https://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#pyfftw.FFTW.__call__) (which wraps `execute` with some additional checks).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `execute()`.

```
pyfftw.FFTW(a,b,axes = (-2,-1), direction = 'FFTW_FORWARD').execute()
```